# NGINX Reverse Proxy to MultiDomain Umbraco site

Tags: nginx, proxy, umbraco7

So basically I have configured the umbraco site with 2 domains i.e xyz.com (main domain and mapped to LB) pointing to english content and xyz.co.in pointing to other language content. This set up works fine. 
Now we introduced a reverse proxy for SEO and performance where in if we browse xyz.co.in it should redirect to a proxy server and internally it forwards the request to LB (i.e xyz.com) . But while forwarding the request , it should keep the host header as xyz.co.in ,which possibly should help Umbraco resolve the content. 
> We are using Nginx as reverse proxy server and the setting inside nginx is 
**proxy_pass xyz.com

proxy_set_header Host xyz.co.in** 

The above setting does not resolve properly and I get 404 .If we set proxy header as xyz.com then it works properly to give english content but not sure how do I get other language content. Does umbraco honor host header to resolve the content mapping or I am missing something here. Any help is greatly appreciated

Regards
Raghav

Comment: Could you post the relevant configuration pieces?  It is much easier to thing about the question when you eliminate the possibility of typos.  Also, please divide your question into paragraphs, it also makes things easier to think about.

Comment: Thanks I have reformatted it a bit, The nginx confguration for reverse proxy is highlighted in bold . For Umbraco ,mapping the host names to different culture is done the usual way.